# Game Of Life not updating the grid

Tags: java, conways-game-of-life

I've been working on this Game of Life homework for a couple of days, and everything is ready, but it seems that the game isn't updating itself, it's not advancing generations. I've checked the loops, but everything seems fine, perhaps I'm forgetting something? This is the class that makes all the work in the program, so it definitely has to be here (besides my teacher giving me most of the code already but this).

```
package juegoDeLaVidaBien;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.Random;

public class Escenario {

    //ESTADO

    private static final int WIDTH = 50;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 50;

    //Utilizaremos un array de booleanos para simular las celulas. True - VIVA.
    private boolean[][] grid;
    private boolean[][] gridNew;



    //COMPORTAMIENTO
    public Escenario() {
        grid = new boolean[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
        gridNew = new boolean[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
    }


    //Creamos, con posiciones y cantidades aleatorias celulas, si el numero random es mayor que la semilla que hemos puesto en la etiqueta
    public void reset(float semilla) {

        if ((Math.random()* (1 - 0 + 1) + 0) > semilla) {

            grid = new boolean[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

            /*
             * Random rand = new Random();
             * 
             * int c = rand.nextInt(WIDTH); int p = rand.nextInt(HEIGHT);
             * 
             * for (int i=0;i<c+50;i++) { while (grid[c][p]) { c = rand.nextInt(WIDTH); p =
             * rand.nextInt(HEIGHT); } grid[c][p] = true; }
             */

            grid[17][20] = true;
            grid[20][17] = true;
            grid[18][20] = true;
            grid[20][18] = true;
            grid[18][19] = true;
            grid[19][21] = true;
            grid[19][20] = true;
            grid[20][20] = true;
        }
        else {
            grid = new boolean[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
        }
}

    //Hace simular celda de manera infinita
    //Calls simulaCelda()
    public void simulaTurno() {

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        simulaCelda(i,j);
    }

     //Pintamos las celulas que SI estén vivas. Las que no, moridas.
     public void pintate(Graphics2D g2d,int w, int h) {

              g2d.setColor(Color.white);
              g2d.fillRect(1, 0, w-2, h-2);

                 for(int i=0;i<grid.length;i++){
                     for(int j=0;j<grid.length;j++) {
                      if (grid[i][j]) {   
                       simulaTurno();
                       pintaCelda(i, j, g2d, w, h); 
                      }
                 } 

             }  

    }
    //Reglas del juego de la vida, el método, la película.
     public void simulaCelda(int i, int j) {


         for (i = 1; i < grid.length - 1; i++) {
                for (j = 1; j < grid[0].length - 1; j++) {
                    gridNew[i][j] = false;
                    int neighbour = 0;
                    if (grid[i - 1][j - 1]) neighbour++; //Noroeste
                    if (grid[i - 1][j]) neighbour++; //Norte
                    if (grid[i - 1][j + 1]) neighbour++; //Noreste
                    if (grid[i][j - 1]) neighbour++; //Oeste
                    if (grid[i][j + 1]) neighbour++; //Este
                    if (grid[i + 1][j - 1]) neighbour++; //Suroeste
                    if (grid[i + 1][j]) neighbour++; //Sur
                    if (grid[i + 1][j + 1]) neighbour++; //Sureste
                    System.out.println("Funca");
                       if (grid[i][j]) {
                            //La celula vive, pero, vivirá?
                            if ((neighbour == 2) || (neighbour == 3)) {
                                gridNew[i][j] = grid[i][j];

                            }
                            //Oh no, superpoblacion, o super-no-poblacion
                            else if((neighbour > 3) || (neighbour < 2)){
                                gridNew[i][j] = false;
                            }
                         }
                          //Las celulas muertas dan a luz?
                        else if ((neighbour == 3) && (grid[i][j] == false)) {
                             gridNew[i][j] = true;   
                        }
                        else {
                            gridNew[i][j] = grid[i][j];
                        }

                }
           }   

     }

    //Pintamos con un rectangulo negro las celulas vivas.
    private void pintaCelda(int i, int j, Graphics2D g2d,int w,int h) {
        int rowWidth;
        int rowHeight;

        rowWidth = w/WIDTH;
        rowHeight = h/HEIGHT;

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect(i*rowWidth, j*rowHeight, rowWidth, rowHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: your grid is never updated? the fields do not move from white to black etc...?

Comment: nope, they don't.

Comment: just showed the first-grid-version and no changing grid?

Comment: Yeah, shows first time and then it doesn't change.

Comment: Where did you program the break time? I can't see it in this class ... You have to define a time how often the grids should be updated and check if they should be black or white

Comment: They have a break in thread.sleep(100) (In an outside controller that was given by the teacher) If that's not it, then the answer to that is 99% no I didn't program it

Comment: You calculate the next generation from `grid` to `gridNew`, then you continue to display `grid`.